# I want to use elastic search for NER

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use elastic search for NER

Imagine that Elastic Search engine has data included key and value.
the key is word. And the value is a list of Entity.
for example; key:apple, value:[fruit, company]

And when I send a query that consisting of a sentence. The sentence can have several candidate keywords. So, my question is whether the functionality is in the Elastic Search that gives results for each candidate keyword in a single query.

Ex)

query : "what is apple pie"
candidate keywords : "what", "what is", "what is apple", "what is apple pie", "is", "is apple", "is apple pie", "apple", "apple pie", "pie"
exist key in DB : "apple", "apple pie", "pie"
returned result : "apple":[fruit, company], "apple pie":[food], "pie":[food]

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I use [CoreNLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/) to perform extraction, given the input to the NLP REST server, the resulting output for the tokenizing, NER, and additional parsing like lemmatization, sentiment, co-ference, etc is stored in elasticsearch for posterior discoverability in terms of how to keep training CoreNLP. This might not be the answer on how to use elasticsearch to nail NLP tasks since CoreNLP is the trainable machine learning tool should be used for this (*or spaCy which is great too*), so I assume you wanted to say "*I want to use elastic search for searching and analyzing extracted NER*", if yes, there you go.